# MySQL import CSV file using regex delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, import

I have a LARGE text file (I'm calling it a CSV file, even though technically it isn't) where each line looks like this:

> col1 *valueA* col2 *valueB* col3 *valueC* ...
>   col1 *valueX* col2 *valueY* col3 *valueZ* ...

Instead of having a line at the top of the file declaring the headers for each column, the name of each column precedes the value for that column in each and every line.

I'm trying to import the values in this file (*valueA*, *valueB*, *valueC*, etc) into a MySQL database. I know I can import the contents of a simpler CSV-style file using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

However, this doesn't really work for the structure of the file I'm trying to import.

As the names of each column in my datafile can have a variable length, I would ideally like to specify a regex (something like `[a-z]{3,}`) for the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` option, but this doesn't work.

So how can I parse this data into a database table?

Comment: How big is "large"?

There are two general approaches: load it into a staging table that mimics the source file structure or preprocess the source file to match your destination table.  The details (platform, hardware, file size) will guide the solution.

Comment: The file contains around 1,000,000 lines. I'm using OS X, on an iMac with a 3.1GHz Core 2 Duo and 8GB of ram, although I have a Linux (Ubuntu) server available for use with many cores (12, I think) and 24GB of ram. I would much prefer to load the data into the database on the Mac, however.